# How to identify Chrome tab responsible for UI slowdown?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with Chrome Version 103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (64-bit) on a fairly fast PC (6 core CPU, 32GB RAM, 1TB SSD). I often have about 150 tabs open. It rarely causes any slowdowns, but occasionally there is a website, which slows the UI down, especially for scrolling or search, producing 1-2s response time. System Monitor doesn't show a tab with high CPU use, each one is well below 1%. `gnome-system-monitor` is on top of the list, reaching 2% from time to time. Are there any other methods to identify the culprit tab(s)?

SOLUTION

The source of slowdowns was hardware acceleration (deceleration in my case). Disabling it in Chrome -> Settings -> System solved my problem.

Comment: @Nmath I wrote: *each one is well below 1%*. For example, right now after reboot I have 3 Chrome tasks at 0.06% and the rest at 0%.

Comment: And how do you know that there is only one problematic tab? I suggest that you use process of elimination. If there is some kind of software tool to assist with this, that would be in the realm of Chrome support. Google Chrome is proprietary software. It's not affiliated with Ubuntu and since the full source code is not available, nobody can completely study how it works. This question may be more topical if you asked somewhere that supports Google Chrome specifically. But even then, it sounds like your problem is with a website, not the application itself, and not the OS either.

Answer (score 1):

User-friendly way: shift-escape in Chrome (and most Chromium-based browsers) will bring up the browser's task manager, which will give you all the info you need!
Also, be aware that even if each "active" tab uses less than 1% CPU, it adds up rather quickly.